# Duplicate Mongoose log entry when using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, es6-promise

I've implemented promises into mongoose but I'm receiving duplicate log entries and I'm not sure if it's the expected output and if so, why?

I run the below function, only once during an if statement.

```
const isUsernameTaken = (username) => {
  let isTaken;
  const promise = User.find({username: username}, (err, doc) => {
    if(doc.length) {
      isTaken = true;
    } else {
      isTaken = false;
    }
  }).exec();
  promise.then(() => {
    return isTaken;
  });
}
```

mongoose debug output

```
Mongoose: users.find({username: 'test'}, {projection: {}})
Mongoose: users.find({username: 'test'}, {projection: {}})
true
```

vs what I would expect

```
Mongoose: users.find({username: 'test'}, {projection: {}})
true
```

Comment: If you remove the `exec()` does it still happen?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've even tried using async await and regular promises but I still receive the same result.

Comment: Wait.. so... when you don't use `exec()` you get the desired output?

Comment: Wait, my bad. I misread that ha! No, it still output duplicates.

Comment: [What does this give you](https://gist.github.com/oze4/8822392db84d038a31f6a087170f558f)?

Comment: That fixes my problem! Thank you.

Comment: I'm going to add that as an answer - just in case someone else has this issue and stumbles upon it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like using a callback for `find`, as well as calling `exec()` is sending the request twice...  Putting the callback inside of `promise.then(...)` should fix it:

```
const isUsernameTaken = (username) => {
  User.find({username: username})
    .exec()
    .then(doc => doc ? true : false)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```